# Converting to Islam and visit to local mosque

Tags: conversion

I discovered Islam a few months ago and I studied it (reading Quran, listening to lectures, learning to read arabic, trying to build a small vocabulary and so on). Now I would like to take it to next level. These days I also learned about making salah (still working on memorizing).

My problem now is that I am not sure what to expect and how to approach the next step. As I already told you I am not a speaker of arabic yet and from what I seen on their facebook page the lectures are given in arabic (I am from Romania if you wonder). Will I look funny standing there and understanding basically nothing? Are new comers welcome generally speaking? I know from other people that in judaism they are not totally friendly to new comers, I wonder if I will experience something like that in Islam as well.

Something else. Is Shahada supposed to be told in front of other two muslims to be true (I found this in various places)? When will I be able to say that I am a muslim?

Any other suggestion helps. Thanks

Comment: Depending on where you are located, local Muslims will communicate and give lectures in english or your local language. Salah is offered in Arabic as a ritual, though its not essential to learn the whole language, many muslims just memorize salah and learn to read arabic without understanding to recite the Quran, and use translations for understanding.

Comment: You don't need to say the Shahadah infront of any witnesses ... see [this answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/39579/20218) on SE and [this one](https://islamqa.info/en/11936) on islamqa. You are a Muslim when you say the Shahada with the intention to become a Muslim.

Comment: Muslims are generally rather friendly and enthusiastic regarding newcomers ... Though people vary from place to place, it may depend.

Comment: all of real Muslims are be friends together.  they are our brothers and sisters in any place.

Comment: Congratulation for converting to Islam, this is really a blessing news to hear. As others mentioned, **Muslims are ALL brothers**; Regarding Shahdah, usually new comers do it in mosque, go to the nearest Mosque. New comers are **always welcome to Islam**

Answer (score 2):

I am a muslim and I don't know Arabic either, but where I am they speak in english for all the lectures. I suggest you  ask your imaam to see if he can do the lecture in a language all can understand.

New comers are generally welcomed in the islamic community, and usually the local people will try to help get you settled in and make you feel comfortable.

The only arabic I know are some surahs in order to recite them in my prayers.

Usually, the shahada is done in front of a muslim community. This will get rid of the need for you to introduce yourself as the imaam will when you say the shahada. And people will come to you and talk to you if they know you just reverted.

Answer (score 0):

The best is to read, recite, and understand the suras as you are performing salah.  If you don't understand then recite.  If you cannot recite then listen to the imam as he recites.

Just as an infant does not understand what the mother is saying, just the sound of her voice has a soothing, healing, and beneficial effect on the infant;
Likewise when you hear the words of Allah (swt), you will have the beneficial effect of mother's words but several orders of magnitude greater.  After **all** it is **All**ah (swt) who created you, so his words as conveyed through our prophet's lips will always beckon a homecoming to you from the diversions of the dunya.  He is omni-present and **all**ways there when you need him.

There are many resources on the Web to learn the Quran and Arabic from the language of your choice through the privacy of Internet connected device.  I would recommend 
www.transliteration.org

Muslim means 'one who whole heartedly submits to Allah' or 'slave of Allah'.  It's in your heart and all living things are born muslim since they were created by Allah (swt).  Humans have the choice of remaining muslim from birth or getting diverted to false deities.

This is a measure of Allah's love for humans.  True love is not by force but by free choice.  Allah loves us so much that he gave us liberty in this regard.

Brother, you are coming back to Islam.  You are reverting, not converting or upgrading.  You were born Muslim, welcome back home.

This reversion is in your heart, and since you came back to Allah after being diverted through your upbringing, Allah will bless you more for demonstrating your sincerity in coming back to him.

While taking shahada in front of witnesses is not necessary, you will not regret the experience.  I would recommend after Juma prayer before the congregation leaves.  Your shehada will bring joy and more faith to you and the entire umma at the masjid.

Welcome home. Selamun Aleykum.