# How to accurately translate ترك in the context of the hadith "Between man and polytheism and unbelief is the [abandonment/negligence] of prayer"?

Tags: salat, hadith, kufr, arabic-translation

There are two similar ahadith with different translations:

> إِنَّ بَيْنَ الرَّجُلِ وَبَيْنَ الشِّرْكِ وَالْكُفْرِ تَرْكَ الصَّلاَةِ
> Verily between man and between polytheism and unbelief is the **negligence** of prayer.
> <sub>[Sahih Muslim 82 a](https://sunnah.com/muslim/1/153)</sub>
>
> بَيْنَ الرَّجُلِ وَبَيْنَ الشِّرْكِ وَالْكُفْرِ تَرْكُ الصَّلاَةِ
> Between man and polytheism and unbelief is the **abandonment** of salat.
> <sub>[Sahih Muslim 82 b](https://sunnah.com/muslim/1/154)</sub>

It looks like the relevant Arabic word is [ترك](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%AA%D8%B1%D9%83), which Wiktionary translates to *to leave, to relinquish*.  The impression I get from the English translation is that it means permanently.

**Question**: How to accurately translate ترك in the context of the hadith "Between man and polytheism and unbelief is the [abandonment/negligence] of prayer"?

This is relevant to my previous question here: [Can someone end up leaving Islam through neglect?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/44887/17163)

Google Translate gives a ranking of translations, favouring "leave" over "neglect":

[image: Google Translate results for ترك]

Comment: As an Arabic speaker and Arabic being my mother tongue, I can unhesitatingly tell you that ترك means “leave off/relinquish” - Neglect (which carries the connotations of ignoring) is definitely NOT the accurate definition. There’s a whole set of Arabic words that mean neglect. As far as ترك being temporarily or permanently, it is dependent on the context of the phrase - which is not explicitly clear from the Hadith you have quoted. Although I have no doubt that the initial reading of the Hadith leans towards a “permanent” meaning, in the sense of someone quitting his prayers.

Comment: Relevant: [concordance within the Quran](http://corpus.quran.com/qurandictionary.jsp?q=trk) and [entry in Lane's Arabic lexicon](https://archive.org/stream/anarabicenglish03lanegoog#page/n310/mode/2up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tark تَركَ can mean to leave/abandon/release with an open probability  to get back to something, whereas in the context of the hadeeth, The word **Tark** تَركَ gives the notion of ceasing to pray, whether that is **permanent** or **willingly** temporary.

### Dismissing Prayers

A related verse that sheds light on the topic of the hadeeth is :

> فَخَلَفَ مِن بَعْدِهِمْ خَلْفٌ أَضَاعُوا الصَّلَاةَ وَاتَّبَعُوا
>   الشَّهَوَاتِ ۖ فَسَوْفَ يَلْقَوْنَ غَيًّا - 19:59

**sahih International translation**

> But there came after them successors who **neglected** prayer and pursued
>   desires; so they are going to meet evil -

**Yousuf Ali Translation**

> But after them there followed a posterity who **missed** prayers and
>   followed after lusts soon, then, will they face Destruction,-

**Quranic wording**

Allah, exalted He is,  eloquently used the term **أَضَاعُوا** which means originally to **lose** something... you lose due to **negligence**, or you lose if you are **willingly** not paying attention or taking care. I think you can see how this word covers the meaning, which is **permanent** or **willingly** temporary.

### **Tark** تَرَكَ in Quran

For your reference, the word **Tark** تَرَكَ in Quran can be one of three meanings:

To reject/abandon/leave intentionally

> **وَتَرَكْنَا** بَعْضَهُمْ يَوْمَئِذٍ يَمُوجُ فِي بَعْضٍ ۖ وَنُفِخَ فِي
>   الصُّورِ فَجَمَعْنَاهُمْ جَمْعًا -
>
> 18:99 And We will **leave** them that day surging over each other, and
>   [then] the Horn will be blown, and We will assemble them in [one]
>   assembly.

another example of leaving willingly, on purpose

> **وَاتْرُكِ** الْبَحْرَ رَهْوًا ۖ إِنَّهُمْ جُندٌ مُّغْرَقُونَ - 44:24 And
>   **leave** the sea in stillness. Indeed, they are an army to be drowned."

The other meaning that appeared in Quran is to be forced/unwillingly to leave/abandon something

> كَمْ تَرَكُوا مِن جَنَّاتٍ وَعُيُونٍ - 44:25 How much they left behind
>   of gardens and springs

Third Meaning is what a person leaves as inheritance after death

> يَسْتَفْتُونَكَ قُلِ اللَّهُ يُفْتِيكُمْ فِي الْكَلَالَةِ ۚ إِنِ
>   امْرُؤٌ هَلَكَ لَيْسَ لَهُ وَلَدٌ وَلَهُ أُخْتٌ فَلَهَا نِصْفُ مَا
>   تَرَكَ ۚ وَهُوَ يَرِثُهَا إِن لَّمْ يَكُن لَّهَا وَلَدٌ ۚ فَإِن
>   كَانَتَا اثْنَتَيْنِ فَلَهُمَا الثُّلُثَانِ مِمَّا **تَرَكَ** ۚ وَإِن
>   كَانُوا إِخْوَةً رِّجَالًا وَنِسَاءً فَلِلذَّكَرِ مِثْلُ حَظِّ
>   الْأُنثَيَيْنِ ۗ يُبَيِّنُ اللَّهُ لَكُمْ أَن تَضِلُّوا ۗ وَاللَّهُ
>   بِكُلِّ شَيْءٍ عَلِيمٌ - 4:176
>
> They request from you a [legal] ruling. Say, " Allah gives you a
>   ruling concerning one having neither descendants nor ascendants [as
>   heirs]." If a man dies, leaving no child but [only] a sister, she will
>   have half of **what he left**. And he inherits from her if she [dies and]
>   has no child. But if there are two sisters [or more], they will have
>   two-thirds of what he left. If there are both brothers and sisters,
>   the male will have the share of two females. Allah makes clear to you
>   [His law], lest you go astray. And Allah is Knowing of all things.

And Allah knows best.