# Must Shahada be said in Arabic?

Tags: conversion, shahada

Without getting into secondary details, if one utters *shahada* in a language other than Arabic (obviously, with the sincere intention to become Muslim), is that person considered a Muslim or must it be in Arabic? (Obviously, uttering it in Arabic is the proper and expected way. My question is whether there unambiguous evidence, if not proof, that any other language except Arabic will not do.)

Comment: Maybe this is covering your inquiry [What is the correct way to become Muslim](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/47198/what-is-the-correct-way-to-become-muslim)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any language a person utters the shahadah in his Islam will be accepted as long as seven conditions are fulfilled

1. knowledge of whats he saying he know it means none has the right to be worshipped except Allah and the prophet Muhammad صلى الله عليه وسلم is the messenger of Allah.
2. certainty meaning he believes 100% in what he is saying is the truth.
3. acceptance meaning he doesn't say the shahdah whilst believing or saying for example i dont believe in certain parta of Islam it is barbaric etc.
4. submission
5. truthfulness meaning not for marriage etc he believes this is different is condition number 2 as this condition means he isn't becoming Muslim for a worldly gain etc.
6. sincerity
7. Love

Some scholars added 8th condition which is to disbelieve in everything worshipped except Allah and to believe only Allah has the right to be worshipped because this real meaning kf shahdah.

Some evidence shahdah can be said in any langauge is

Surah 14 verse 4

> And We did not send any messenger except [speaking] in the language of his people to state clearly for them, and Allah sends astray [thereby] whom He wills and guides whom He wills. And He is the Exalted in Might, the Wise.

Comment: What is the source of these conditions?

Comment: As sallamu alaykum wa rahmatullah ahsanu allahu ilayk akhi alkareem  the source is from personal lessons with different teachers in my city but these conditions are well known that they are conditions the brother wanted basic answer so i didnt delve in too much.

Comment: I read many fatwas saying that it must be uttered in Arabic. So I wondered about the source.

Comment: I will speak to someone about it insha'Allah ja za kallahu khayran